# Handsontable. Get a list of all validation errors

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm wondering if is possible to get a list of all validation errors in handsontable before submit the data?

Thanks!

Comment: This is something I'm dealing with as well. I think it would be a handy feature to add. Might be worth opening an Improvement Suggestion on Github (https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues)

Answer (score 4):

Add listener to afterValidate event
http://handsontable.com/demo/validation.html
more here
https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Events
afterValidate (isValid: Boolean, value: Mixed, row: Number, prop: String, source: String)

after this in handler function you can write JQuery selector to extract the error data.

**UPDATE** as per request

well you attach event listener like this, then [according to documentation](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.17.0/Hooks.html#event:afterValidate)

```
$('#your-handsontable-id').on('afterValidate', function(result){
   if(!result.isValid){
    alert('Take your pants off cause we have a problem boy! - value - '+ result.value +' row -' + result.row +' prop -' + result.prop+ +' source-'+result.source); 
   }
});
```

Comment: This is pretty vague. Can you describe how you would store data regarding which validation rules were violated?